Как защитить исходный код проекта написанный на Python?
Да, я знаю, что python - это не компилятор, а интерпретатор и знаю, что можно делать самораспоковывающийся архив.
Но вопрос в другом. Например, если речь идет о продаже проекта, то как можно защитить код от утечки? Мне на ум приходит только вариант взять сформировать docker-образ и залить его в репозиторий. Но, все равно код можно прочитать - достаточно зайти в запущенный контейнер и вытащить оттуда целехонькие файлы.
Есть ли способ какого-то "компилирования" проекта (например, написанного на FastAPI, Flask или Django с кучей всяких модулей и роутов) или единственный способ через сборку докер-образа?

А зачем вы в заголовке вопроса пишете совсем не то, что в вопросе? У вас вопрос про защиту кода - ну так и пишите в заголовке. Компилированный код обычно никак не защищён от декомпилирования обратно в исходный код.

ну, это уже другой вопрос) Например, ты написал какую-то технологию и ей могут пользоваться как продуктом, но саму технологию ты не продал или еще что-нибудь в этом роде.

Единственный по настоящему надёжный способ - не передавать исходный код или скомпилированную программу в третьи руки. Заведите сервер, поместите туда программу и продавайте доступ к API.

Ну это понятно, а что делать с закрытым контуром?

@CrazyElf, поменял

Единственный надёжный способ не потерять деньги на развиваемом продукте в наше время - это продавать поддержку, обновляемый контент и прочее такое, что нельзя просто взять и скопировать. Всё, что физически можно скопировать - будет скопировано, как не ухищряйся.

Купите ноутбук, установите туда сервер с вашей программой, зашифруйте диск, закройте доступ к периферии, запустите сервер, внесите ноут в закрытый контур, присоедините к сети. Тоже самое можно сделать с (мини)десктопом.

Вопрос этот в пространство, поэтому и ответы соответствующие, то есть тоже в пространство. Я проработал несколько лет в банке и имею представление об общих принципах безопасности, попробую здесь направить размышления в предметное русло. Если чётко понимать что именно надо защитить, это уже половина ответа.

Допустим, я не хочу делиться своими технологиями. Ну, не думаю же я всерьёз, что одна программа будет кормить меня всю жизнь. Та берите. Уже давно доказано, что чужие технологии могут помочь, сократить время разработки, но не сделают из человека без способностей программиста никогда. Многие пытаются, например, делать лоадеры, которые расшифровывают тексты исполняемых программ. Можно поймать, если постараться, расшифрованный код. Сливают всё и вся, программисты увольняются и пользуются своими наработками в других местах работы. Базы данных продаются и конвертируются. В стране, где не уважают авторское право других, не стоит ждать иного отношения к себе.

Базы данных. Какие? Локальные, сетевые, веб? Шифрование с открытым ключом, защита со стороны сервера. Даже в этом случае можно сделать скриншот или сфотографировать экран с секретными данными. Камеры наблюдения в офисе и надсмотрщик. Это скорее административный вопрос - стукачество, стимулирование лояльности и прочее в этом духе.

Действия. Тоже зависит от ситуации. Там, где рано или поздно придётся расследовать инцидент, не ленятся писать логирование на каждом этапе действий пользователя.

Можно попытаться контролировать процесс взлома скриптов с помощью цифровых подписей, созданных для файлов.

Всегда нужно помнить о том, что паяльник - универсальный дешифратор паролей. Всё должно быть максимально децентрализовано, сдублировано, логировано. Служба безопасности постоянно должна заниматься моделированием ситуаций и учениями, сама должна постоянно пытаться совершить учебный взлом, уметь мыслить как взломщик. Для того, чтоб эффективно противостоять в реальной ситуации.


Ну вот так примерно надо рассуждать. Вопрос должен поэтапно детализироваться. В процессе появятся и ответы.

У человека простой проект, написанный одним человеком, судя по всему. А вы ему предлагаете банковскую структуру безопасности. )

Я мысли читать умею? Я пока не вижу уточнения целей. Есть и другие, которых тема может заинтересовать. Я учу думать, детализуя задачу. Особенно я люблю истории, когда пользуются взломанными программными продуктами, а когда своё творение обнаруживают в свободном полёте, спрашивают: "А меня-то почему-то обокрали?". Или ходят и рассказывают друг другу сказки о суперзащите. Если б она существовала, мы бы все уже жили в одной большой кибертюрьме под наблюдением Всевидящего ока Большого Брата. Без шансов на освобождение.

Что касается простого проекта, то это пункт 1. НЕ будет одна программа кормить всю жизнь. Такие случаи единичны (типа Facebook, да и то это сложный комплекс программ, написанный многими). Тут написал, сдал, получил деньги, там поработал, уволился, пошёл дальше. Да и время не стоит на месте. Через 10 лет программирование БУДЕТ ДРУГИМ. Оно уже сегодня становится другим! Я уже в этом участвую помаленьку. Лично Вам могу сообщить тайну о том, какое оно будет. Программист-закорючкописатель будет постановщиком задач для ИИ. Какие защиты сегодняшнего дня? Это всё будет смешным совсем скоро.
